# getting permission or paying fee to use the System Usability Scale (SUS)

Tags: sus, copyright

I am trying to use SUS scale in my study, but wondering about the process of getting permission or paying the fee for using the scale. I could not get any hint from Google search. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's free and you don't need any permissions, just mention the methodology used in any published work. It's a bit outdated and unreliable, though. Even the page in [usability.gov](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/system-usability-scale.html) states that everything there may be incorrect and/or out of date.

> Usability.gov is archived and no longer updated
>
> External links may not function and information on the site may be out
> of date. Visit digital.gov for current information.

and a search for SUS on digital.gov leads to the same page in a loop, so...